# Adding UNIQUE click listeners to each dynamically-created element

Tags: jquery

I see a lot of answers for adding click listeners to dynamically-created elements involving the use of the .on method for applying listeners to all members of a class, present and future. That's probably a great batch technique that works for the majority of circumstances, but I'm looking for something a little MORE dynamic. The code below isn't correct, but I believe it will give you a good idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
            var nav = [
                {
                    id:'newGL',
                    text:'new'
                    type:'iframe'
                },
                {
                    id:'litGL',
                    text:'lit',
                    type:'iframe'
                }
            ]
function loadNav(nav){
    for(navItem in nav){
        var id = navItem.id;
        var text = navItem.text;
        var type = navItem.type;
        var html = "<div>" + text + "</div>";
        $(html).click(function(){
            getContent(id,type);
        });
        $('#horzNav').append(html);
    }
}
```

I'm just trying to avoid a situation where I have to create the element with an id and then re-find it again after appending in order to add the click listener. There's got to be a better way, right?

Comment: what is more dynamic than using event delegation? You have access to the element event occurred on using `this` inside handler. Provide use case explanation why it won't work for you. You don't need ID's to make it work, just use common classes for common elements

Comment: These id's don't have anything to do with html id's. They are passed to an ajax call and sent to a server-side script. Common classes won't work because none of these elements have anything in common. Each of them sends a unique id to a script and receives back unique content to be displayed depending on the id sent in the ajax call.

Comment: of course they have something on common... one class will call one api endpoint...then get the data from the element. This is done all the time on large scale using event delegation. Not hard at all to make it work with delegation... or combinations of class(s) and data dictate endpoint url and what gets sent or done with response .